# Script Trigger: Function to run is grayed out

Tags: eventtrigger

I have created a new sheet that grabs data out of an email.  I am trying to set up the Trigger to pull the data on a timely basis, but have run into an issue.  I have rebooted, cleared cookies, cache etc ... however, though I can set event source, type of time-based trigger, and more, I can not set 'Choose which function to run'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Wkh.png)